# How do I get dataset from the query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, dataset, dataadapter

I have the following SQL query in MS Access / VB.net:

```
    Dim sql = "SELECT [Product Name], [Customer Name], [Group Associated], [Customer Address], [Product Price], [Current Stock], [Date Ordered], [Volume Purchased] FROM (torder INNER JOIN tproducts ON tproducts.Product_ID = torder.Product_ID) INNER JOIN tcustomer ON torder.Customer_ID = tcustomer.Customer_ID WHERE torder.[Date Ordered] Between #" & StartOfTimePeriod & "# And #" & Today & "#;"
    conn.Open()
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "torder")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView.DataMember = "torder"
```

When the query is run it doesn't display the full dataset that it should. Instead, the results are almost random. What could be wrong?

http://prntscr.com/5eh4ge

http://prntscr.com/5eh4ai

Comment: What are you expecting? How many records you get when run this query in msaccess and when you run using application?

Comment: What type is [Date Ordered] in the database table definition?

Comment: [Date Ordered] is a Date/Time

Comment: Is Windows configured to use the `dd/mm/yyyy` short date format?

Answer (score 2):

Do not stringize your date and time values. Use a parameterized query.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT [Product Name], [Customer Name], [Group Associated], " & _
          "[Customer Address], [Product Price], [Current Stock], [Date Ordered], " & _
          "[Volume Purchased] " & _
          "FROM (torder INNER JOIN tproducts ON tproducts.Product_ID = torder.Product_ID) " & _
          "INNER JOIN tcustomer ON torder.Customer_ID = tcustomer.Customer_ID " & _
          "WHERE torder.[Date Ordered] >= ? And torder.[Date Ordered] <= ?"

Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
Dim p1 = new OleDbParameter() With 
{
    .ParameterName = "@p1",
    .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date,
    .Value = StartOfTimePeriod
}
Dim p1 = new OleDbParameter() With 
{
    .ParameterName = "@p2",
    .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date,
    .Value = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(1339)
}
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p1)
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p2)
....
```

In this way the correct interpretation of your DateTime values is a job passed to the database engine together with actual DateTime values (I assume that StartOfTimePeriod is a DateTime variable). 
Instead, if you convert these values to string, the conversion follow the rules of your locale environment that could produce a string not compatible with the expected format of your database engine (for example the inversion of position of months and days values)